# Is there a way Typescript can correctly infer that array.at(x) must be defined?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an array that might be empty:

```
const cheeses: string[] = ...

console.log('my favorite cheese is ', 
  cheeses.length > 0 ? cheeses.at(-1)?.toUpperCase() : 'GORGONZOLA'
)
```

This throws a type error at `cheeses.at(-1)`: `Object is possibly undefined.`

I can fix it with (much uglier) `cheeses[cheeses.length - 1].toUpperCase()` (though that in fact seems to circumvent any type guard, since I can also call `[cheeses.length - 10]` without error.)

Is there a way to make Typescript (4.6.x) infer that `cheeses.at(-1)?` must be defined?

Comment: What do you mean with "infer"? How would TypeScript know which elements are accessible and which are out of bounds if `chesses` is not a tuple. Just use the `!` operator if you are sure that it can not be undefined.

Comment: @TobiasS. this doesn't seem like an unreasonable ask i.e. that the compiler can infer from the length check that the object at the end of the array cannot be undefined.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I am not sure about that one: https://tsplay.dev/wER6kN

Comment: This is like [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/69368851/type-safe-way-of-narrowing-type-of-arrays-by-length-when-nouncheckedindexedacces) except it's asking specifically about `.at()` which is still "too complex" according to [ms/TS#47660](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660).  I could write up an answer if you want (please mention me via @jcalz if you want me to do something), or I could close this as a duplicate of the other.  In short, though, this is beyond the compiler's abilities.  You might as well write `(cheeses.at(-1)??"gorgonzola").toUpperCase()` and move on